# Problem with proof of Rolle's theorem.

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove Rolle's theorem. [This link](http://www.math.hmc.edu/calculus/tutorials/mean_value/proof_rolle.pdf%E2%80%8E) makes the following argument:

> If $f$ attains a maximum in $ [a,\ b] $ at the point $c$, then $ f'(c) = 0 $.

Although this is a pretty well known fact, I hardly think it is rigorous. Can I please see a proof of this? One way to go about it would be to say that we have to assume the continuity of $ f' $. But someone told me Rolle's theorem does not require $ f' $ to be continuous.

Comment: The link is a pdf. www.math.hmc.edu/calculus/tutorials/mean_value/proof_rolle.pdf‎

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_theorem_(stationary_points)#Proof_2:_Extremum_implies_derivative_vanishes. Your link is not working by the way

Comment: @dani_s- The proof given on the wikipedia link is valid only fi $f'(x)$ is continuous.

Comment: Where is it using that $f'$ is continuous?

Comment: Sorry my bad. It just requires the existence of the derivative. Thanks!

Comment: I think $f'(c)$ exists is enough.

Comment: As you state the theorem it reminds me more Fermat's theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_theorem_(stationary_points)

Comment: Why do you need proofs of obvious things?

Comment: @Awesome- Because sometimes "obvious" things are untrue.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is differentiable on $]a,b[$ and $c \in]a,b[$ is a minimum of $f$, then for $x$ in $]a,b[$, $f(x)-f(c) \geq 0$.

Thus for $x \in ]c,b[$, $\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} \geq 0$ so by taking the limit $x \to c$, $f'(c) \geq 0$.

But for $x \in ]a,c[$, $\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} \leq 0$ so by taking the limit $x \to c$, $f'(c) \leq 0$.